# Error while running eclipse in liferay platform

Tags: environment-variables

i am new to liferay and is managed to start the liferay sever by setting the environment variable, but when i create a liferay plugin project it doesnt work and shows 
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\JDK1.7.0_79;

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

whereas the server is running correctly due to correct path of java_home

please help

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, processes cache the environment variables. So if you have changed the environment variables when eclipse was open, new environment variables won't be reflected in eclipse. To solve that problem You can close eclipse and open it from a new instance of windows explorer. If this doesn't solve the problem, open it from the command line with a -clean parameter.

```
D:\eclipse>eclipse.exe -clean
```